# Schema.org Nested Event not Parsing Correctly

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets

I'm marking up my content with schema.org and I've run into a slight problem. I'm using the [BarOrPub](http://schema.org/BarOrPub) schema. As you see in the link, it inherits the "event" property from Place, though it doesn't appear to come from Place in the hierarchy. When I paste my code into the [Rich Snippets Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) it shows the extracted information correctly, but the preview says there is an error. If I remove the `itemprop="event"` from the SocialEvent, it shows the preview correctly, and the information is extracted correctly (Though it's not laid out the way I need it). If I change BarOrPub to Place, which contains the "event" property, they both work correctly. What should I do?

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BarOrPub">
<div>
    <img itemprop="image" src="57.jpg">
    <div>
        <h1 itemprop="name">NameOfPlace</h1>
        <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
            <div itemprop="ratingValue">4.07</div>
            <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="15"/>
        </div>
        <p itemprop="telephone">(316) 263-4044</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="barhalfpad">
        <h2>Upcoming Events</h2>
        <p>
            <table>
                <tr  itemprop="event" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SocialEvent">
                    <td>
                        5/18<meta itemprop="startDate" content="2012-05-18T21:30:00-07:00">
                    </td>
                    <td>21:30:00</td>
                    <td itemprop="name">
                        Event Name
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there isn't a very strict format on how the schema is marked up, google even allows false ratings and reviews for now... I had the same problem but I've seen examples on big sites marked up with lots of non existent properties, ( custom or extended properties http://www.schema.org/docs/extension.html ) google will parse everything anyway :) I left some embedded items that weren't producing errors, the ones that did, I just marked them with itemscope itemtype without itemprop from the parent element. Working good for now.

offtopic edit: Today google changed the rich snippet testing tool, it's even worse than the previous one it only allows 1500 characters, and now you need to select snippets of the html code to test instead of pasting the whole code and extracting the data, bummer :S